# Pedir deferimento. Qual é o correto e por quê?

Tags: pontuação, vírgula

Em cartas mais formais e requerimentos é comum ler o seguinte:

> Termos em que, pede/peço deferimento.

ou

> Termos em que pede/peço deferimento.

Qual dos dois é o correto e por quê?

Comment: Eu sinceramente não consigo entender a função sintática desse "que" na frase. Minha impressão é de que a vírgula é incorreta, mas não tenho certeza. Essa construção é típica de "juridiquês". Podiam muito bem dizer "Nesses termos, peço deferimento", ou "Nos termos acima, peço [o] deferimento...".

Comment: @bfavaretto, é o pronome relativo: refere-se a "termos", e integra o constituinte relativo *em que*, que é adjunto adverbial de *pede*.  E portanto, como intuiste, não pode levar vírgula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obrigatoriamente sem vírgula. A frase em questão aparece em textos com a seguinte estrutura¹ [(ver exemplo aqui)](http://www.dhnet.org.br/denunciar/agitar/direito/sosreq.htm):

> José Silva, dado que X, Y e W, solicita Z, termos ***em que*** pede deferimento

Nesta frase, “termos” refere-se ao enunciado anterior—“dado que […] solicita Z”—e é modificado pela oração relativa restritiva “em que pede deferimento”—não são uns termos quaisquer, são especificamente os termos em que se pede deferimento. O constituinte relativo *em que* é parte integrante da oração relativa, desempenhando a função de adjunto adverbial do verbo *pedir*—*pede deferimento nestes termos*. Ora o constituinte relativo nunca se separa por uma vírgula do resto da oração a que pertence. Pensa nutras estruturas mais simples com orações relativas em que o mesmo acontece (a oração relativa está em itálico, o constituinte relativo a negrito itálico):

> Gostei imenso do livro ***que*** me deste.
>   Vi ontem o episódio ***em que*** Jon Snow ressuscita.
>   Ele contou-me essa mesma história, ***em que*** eu não acredito nem um bocadinho.
>   Acordamos os termos ***em que*** se vão desenrolar as negociações.
>   Choveu imenso, ***o que*** não me impediu de gozar o passeio pela serra.

E como nós gostamos de coisas fundamentadas, aqui ficam uns exemplos de gramáticas conceituadas com o mesmo tipo de construção. O primeiro vem na *Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (Lisboa, 2014, p. 434; minha formatação em todos os exemplos):

> Ela então consentiu que eu erguesse seu rosto, gesto ***que*** não me haviam autorizado.

Os seguintes são da *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (Lisboa, 2013, vol. II, p. 2088):

> (51) a. Estava a chover, situação/facto ***que*** nos causou muito transtorno.
>          b. Chegámos tarde, coisa/motivo ***que*** provocou a ira dos donos da casa.

Estas frases são explicadas na *Gramática do Português* (p. 2087-8) como “construções apositivas contendo um nome abstrato como *coisa, facto, motivo* e *situação* (entre outros) modificado por uma oração relativa restritiva de nome […]”. No exemplo da *Nova Gramática*, o nome abstrato é *gesto*; nos tais requerimentos é *termos*.

---

¹ Um requerimento a sério seria uma ou várias páginas; cada um dos meus pontos X, Y e W, e outros que houvesse, seria um parágrafo, terminando com ponto final; e *termos em que pede deferimento* seria também um parágrafo, começando com maiúscula. Isto não acontece no discurso normal, em que *termos* viria sempre depois de vírgula e com minúscula.

Comment: *não acontece no discurso normal* – isso é o que me chama a atenção nesse tipo de construção, mais do que a eventual vírgula incorreta.

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu também acho esse *termos em que...* particularmente deselegante: em linguagem normal, nestas construções, *termos* referir-se-ia à frase anterior, não a uma série de parágrafos. Mas a vírgula é absolutamente ilegal.

Answer (score 0):

A regra básica é observar se o sujeito concorda (em gênero, número e grau) com o predicado. 
Geralmente inicia-se a carta com “Fulano(s) de Tal, (e segue apresentação de Fulano), REQUER…” — na terceira pessoa (singular ou plural). E por fim, deve –se encerrar com “nestes termos, (Fulano de Tal, o requerente, 3ª pessoa singular) pede (3ª pessoa do singular) deferimento…”
[enter link description here](https://gustavodandrea.com/10-dicas-de-ouro-para-aprimorar-sua-escrita-juridica/)
[enter link description here](http://blog.conamp.org.br/dicas-de-escrita-saiba-escrever-textos-juridicos-de-qualidade/)
[image]

Comment: Bem-vinda Adriana! É ótimo ganharmos mais contribuintes tão ativos, então permita-me mencionar dois pontos recorrentes que podem ser melhorados nas tuas postagens até aqui: 1) as imagens de livros não são necessárias, elas mais distraem do que auxiliam na compreensão da resposta; e 2) lembre de preencher o `enter link description here` com os dados (autor, título ou domínio, etc) do link. Este último ponto é importante por duas razões: i) é possível buscar a referência caso o link apodreça (i.e., seu endereço mude), e ii) não é preciso seguir o link para saber-se qual a referência indicada.

Comment: Nessa resposta específica, não vi conexão entre a referência dada e o texto da resposta - deixei de ver (você poderia apontar?) ou é apenas uma referência genérica sobre o assunto? Se for o último caso, referências do tipo devem ser evitadas.